# How do I unpivot a result of a query with sum Case when involving inner joins of many tables?

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a mission to query various tables and sum up their values based on options selected by the user and the way that i found to do that came from here by using sum case when then and else.
Now my dilema is that i am able to get the results but the are structured only in columns but i would love them to be structured in rows, so i discovered pivot and unpivot but unfortunately i can't get my results in rows.

Here is my query:

select

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN opcao = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opcao = 'DEF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as DEF,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opcao = 'GHI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as GHI,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opcao = 'JKL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as JKL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN opcao = 'MNO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MNO,
    
from
    paciente_paciente pp
    inner join coleta_preenchimento cp on cp.paciente_id = pp.paciente_id
    inner join coleta_preenchimento_pergunta cpp on cpp.preenchimento_id = cp.preenchimento_id
    inner join coleta_pergunta_opcao cpo  on cpo.opcao_id = cpp.opcao_id
    inner join coleta_atendimento_formulario caf on caf.preenchimento_id = cp.preenchimento_id
    inner join coleta_atendimento ca on ca.atendimento_id = caf.atendimento_id
where
    ca.status = 'FINALIZADO'
    and cpp.pergunta_id= 1076
```

Result that I am getting:

| ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Result expected:

| OPTION | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 0 |
| DEF | 1 |
| GHI | 1 |
| JKL | 0 |
| MNO | 1 |

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want to be aggregating by the `opcao` column here.  And you should start the query with the table `coleta_pergunta_opcao` and then left join out.

```sql
SELECT opcao AS OPTION, COUNT(ca.atendimento_id) AS VALUE
FROM coleta_pergunta_opcao cpo
LEFT JOIN coleta_preenchimento_pergunta cpp
    ON cpo.opcao_id = cpp.opcao_id AND
       cpp.pergunta_id = 1076
LEFT JOIN coleta_preenchimento cp
    ON cpp.preenchimento_id = cp.preenchimento_id
LEFT JOIN paciente_paciente pp
    ON cp.paciente_id = pp.paciente_id
LEFT JOIN coleta_atendimento_formulario caf
    ON caf.preenchimento_id = cp.preenchimento_id
LEFT JOIN coleta_atendimento ca
    ON ca.atendimento_id = caf.atendimento_id AND
       ca.status = 'FINALIZADO'
GROUP BY
    opcao;
```

Comment: Thanks for thr help. I tried out the code and its fetching a whole lot of other options than these 5 that i specified here.

Comment: The results should be based only on these 5 options like i demonstrated in my question but just that i need to have them in rows either than in columns.

Comment: Anyways, thank you. I was able to change somethings and achieved the desired result thanks to your code.